# Ext.JS 5: How to use single components (combobox)

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

I've just downloaded the trial version of Ext JS 5 and I'm wondering how to use a single component instead of the whole framework. The Ext's guide doesn't seem to have a guide on this. I'm trying to use this http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/form/combos.html

Can I just include a JS and some images like jQuery UI?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home) you could add the following cdn files (or pull them local) and it'll load the extjs framework.  Then you could add `Ext.onReady` and create extjs elements on your page:

**Js Files Required:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/commercial/5.1.1/build/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/commercial/5.1.1/packages/ext-theme-crisp/build/ext-theme-crisp.js"></script>
```

**CSS Files Required:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/commercial/5.1.1/packages/ext-theme-crisp/build/resources/ext-theme-crisp-all-debug_01.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/commercial/5.1.1/packages/ext-theme-crisp/build/resources/ext-theme-crisp-all-debug_02.css">
```

And here is an example `index.html` file that loads a message box when `Ext` is ready:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/commercial/5.1.1/build/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/commercial/5.1.1/packages/ext-theme-crisp/build/ext-theme-crisp.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/commercial/5.1.1/packages/ext-theme-crisp/build/resources/ext-theme-crisp-all-debug_01.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/commercial/5.1.1/packages/ext-theme-crisp/build/resources/ext-theme-crisp-all-debug_02.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Ext.onReady(function () {
            Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
                title: 'Hello World!',
                items: [{
                    html: 'Another Item Here'
                }]
            }).show();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>TEST SITE</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit 1 (Adding Combobox):**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/commercial/5.1.1/build/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/commercial/5.1.1/packages/ext-theme-crisp/build/ext-theme-crisp.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/commercial/5.1.1/packages/ext-theme-crisp/build/resources/ext-theme-crisp-all-debug_01.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/commercial/5.1.1/packages/ext-theme-crisp/build/resources/ext-theme-crisp-all-debug_02.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Ext.onReady(function () {
            Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
                title: 'Hello World!',
                items: [{
                    html: 'Another Item Here'
                }]
            }).show();
            Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                renderTo:'testDiv',
                width: 500,
                height: 500,
                title: 'This is another test',
                items: [{
                    html: 'Another test here too.'
                },{
                    xtype:'combobox',
                    width:400,
                    displayField: 'descr',
                    valueField: 'descr',
                    store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
                        fields:['descr'],
                        data: [{
                            descr: 'Example 1'
                        },{
                            descr: 'Example 2'
                        }]
                    })
                }]
            })
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>TEST SITE</p>
    <div id="testDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It worked fine, but can you post examples of how to make the combobox work (the link is in the question)

Comment: I'm trying the first code snippet from the link I've posted and I'm getting "Ext.regModel is not a function"

Comment: @KV i added an edit to the solution with a combobox added to the panels array.

Comment: Thank you! It worked but it's missing the autocomplete feature and the code it's a little different from the example I've posted. Why? I'm trying to understand each line. You've started with a panel (Ext.panel.Panel) and the example I've seen with an Ext.form.field.ComboBox. What's the main difference?